# How do I test a simple class?

Tags: c#

> Create an Employee class. Items to include as data members are
>   employee number, name, date of hire, job description, department, and
>   monthly salary. The class is often used to display an alphabetical
>   listing of all employees. Include appropriate constructors and
>   properties. Override the ToString ( ) method to return all data
>   members. Create a second class to test your Employee class.

I've created an Employee class with the proper variables, properties, and constructors, but am having trouble "testing" it through a second class. The code I have written runs without errors, but doesn't display anything (presumably the goal of the testing). Where am I going wrong in the calling section?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeProgram
{
    public class EmployeeProgram
    {
        private int employeeNumber;
        private string name;
        private string hiredate;
        private int monthlySalary;
        private string description;
        private string department;

        public employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary, string description, string department)
        {
            this.employeeNumber = 456;
            this.name = "Joyce";
            this.hiredate = "12/15/14";
            this.monthlySalary = 3200;
            this.description = "Manager";
            this.department = "Accounting";
        }

        public int EmployeeNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

        public string Hiredate
        {
            get
            {
                return hiredate;
            }
            set
            {
                hiredate = value;
            }
        }

        public int MonthlySalary
        {
            get
            {
                return monthlySalary;
            }
            set
            {
                monthlySalary = value;
            }
        }
        public string Department
        {
            get
            {
                return department;
            }
            set
            {
                department = value;
            }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return description;
            }
            set
            {
                description = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Employee ID: " + employeeNumber +
                   "Employee Name: " + name +
                   "Employee Hire Date: " + hiredate +
                   "Employee Monthly Salary: " + monthlySalary +
                   "Employee Description: " + description +
                   "Employee Department: " + department;
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not C++, please don't tag unrelated programming languages. Also, without knowing any C#, this looks like it needs a [mcve] instead of this blob of code.

Comment: Show us your main program

Answer (score -1):

From the code you have posted, you don't call Console.WriteLine() anywhere. You have a Print method, but it won't be run until it is called. You need to create an instance of the class, then write the instance's ToString method to the console, or you can call the method Print on the instance.

In main you can do

```
Employee someone = new Employee(1, "John", "01/01/2016", 5000, "Engineer", "R&D");
Console.WriteLine(someone.ToString());
Console.ReadKey(); // Prevent the console from closing
```

In your Employee constructor, you should probably use the parameters it asks for, like this

```
this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber.
```

You should generally avoid having parameter names that match member variables/properties.

When you don't do anything special in your get and set properties, you can use auto properties

```
public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
```